# Send message As a reply to specific server's channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have 2 guilds and the BOT is in both guilds.
The Bot works like this.
When I send a message from guild 1, the BOT copies the message and sends it to guild 2.

The requirement of making a BOT is working well but I want to make it as a reply to the message when the BOT sends it to guild 2.

Here is the CODE

> ```
> const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('881014432841490452')
> const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(chname => chname.name === 'general')
>
> channel.send(message)**
> ```

If someone knows please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make a message in the same time reply to a message and make that message appear on another guild. When you reply to a message it **will** be on the same channel as the original message.

The only solution you have is to send the message with the URL so people can click it and access the original message:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('881014432841490452')
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'general')

channel.send(`Link : ${message.url}\nContent : ${message.content}`)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working (I can do to the original message)
BUT can't we do it as a reply?

Comment: no discord doesn't allow that so it's physically not possible to reply to a message in a channel from a different channel

Comment: No problem ! If I answer your question click the check mark on my answer and give it an upvote :D

Comment: Marked -> Done, Sir :)